# SQL Server CTE problem

Tags: sql-server, query, cte

This question is in reference to my last question: [SQL Server 08: Union over while](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/sql-server-08-union-over-while)

I'm writing a CTE to do what was described in that question (find available time slots over a given number of days.

I have a CTE written, but I can't quite grasp how to get my date incrementing and limited. As it stands, it only gets data from the 2011-07-30 (@ArrivalDate). **Can anybody explain to me how I can get it properly incrementing, and where I'm going wrong?**

**Update:** I've come up with a better query for getting all the available time slots

```
(SELECT TS.UKTNN, TS.TimeSlotID, TS.TimeSlotGroupID 
 FROM FittingCentreTimeSlotGroupTimeSlots TS)
EXCEPT
(Select BFD.UKTNN, BFD.TimeSlotID, BFD.TimeSlotGroupID 
 From BookedFittingDates BFD)
```

And here is the table structure as requested in the comments:

**TimeSlotGroup**
*UKTNN*, *TimeSlotGroupID*, TimeSlotGroupDesc

**TimeSlotGroupTimeSlots**
*UKTNN*, *TimeSlotID*, *TimeSlotGroupID*, TimeSlotDesc

**BookedDates**
*UKTNN*, *TimeSlotGroupID*, *TimeSlotID*, *Date*

Here is what my existing CTE looks like right now

```
Use[DEV_UKTN_DATA]
GO 
DECLARE @UKTNN int;
DECLARE @ArrivalDate date;
DECLARE @NumDays int;
DECLARE @LoopDate date;

SET @UKTNN = 7;
SET @ArrivalDate = '2011-07-30';
SET @LoopDate = @ArrivalDate;
SET @NumDays = 2;

WITH GetTimeSlotsOnDays(TimeSlotGroupID, TimeSlotGroupDesc, TimeSlotID, TimeSlotDescription, AdditionalCost, UKTNN, CurrentDate, Distance)
AS
(
    SELECT TSG.TimeSlotGroupID, 
           TSG.TimeSlotGroupDesc, 
           TS.TimeSlotID, 
           TS.TimeSlotDescription, 
           TS.AdditionalCost,
           @UKTNN AS UKTNN,
           @ArrivalDate as CurrentDate,
           0 As Distance
    FROM FittingCentreBranchTimeSlotGroups TSG
    INNER JOIN FittingCentreTimeSlotGroupTimeSlots TS 
               ON TSG.TimeSlotGroupID = TS.TimeSlotGroupID AND 
                  TSG.UKTNN = TS.UKTNN
    WHERE TSG.UKTNN = @UKTNN AND
          TS.UKTNN = @UKTNN AND
          TS.TimeSlotGroupID = TSG.TimeSlotGroupID AND
          NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT * 
                FROM BookedFittingDates BFD 
                WHERE BFD.TimeSlotGroupID = TS.TimeSlotGroupID AND 
                      BFD.TimeSlotID = TS.TimeSlotID AND
                      BFD.UKTNN = @UKTNN AND
                      BFD.Date = @ArrivalDate)
          --@ArrivalDate <= DATEADD(DAY, @NumDays, @ArrivalDate) 

    UNION ALL --Recursion starts here

    SELECT TSG.TimeSlotGroupID, 
           TSG.TimeSlotGroupDesc, 
           TS.TimeSlotID, 
           TS.TimeSlotDescription, 
           TS.AdditionalCost,
           @UKTNN UKTNN,
           @ArrivalDate As CurrentDate,
           Distance + 1 As Distance
    FROM FittingCentreBranchTimeSlotGroups TSG
    INNER JOIN FittingCentreTimeSlotGroupTimeSlots TS 
               ON TSG.TimeSlotGroupID = TS.TimeSlotGroupID AND 
                  TSG.UKTNN = TS.UKTNN
    INNER JOIN GetTimeSlotsOnDays as GTSOD
               ON GTSOD.CurrentDate = DATEADD(DAY, Distance, @ArrivalDate)
)


SELECT *
FROM GetTimeSlotsOnDays GTSOD
WHERE GTSOD.CurrentDate = @ArrivalDate AND GTSOD.Distance = 0
ORDER BY GTSOD.TimeSlotGroupID ASC, GTSOD.TimeSlotID ASC
GO
```

Comment: I think you might need to go as far as providing full DDL for the tables involved and sample data inserts. With that, I expect we could come up with a set based query and eliminate the recursion.

Comment: Going to update my post now. Made a (much simpler) query using set logic to get just the available dates. Now I just need to find out how to increment the date properly

Comment: By providing DDL and scripts I meant CREATE TABLE statements and data inserts.

Comment: My apologies. I'll spend some time writing those again and post them when I have them!

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer for this!

1) Create a function that returns a table containing the desired dates

2) Do a cartesian product of the timeslots with the dates

3) Find the exceptions between the booked dates and the cartesian product